# Slow CORB execution on Replicated Environment (with loadbalancer)

Tags: performance, indexing, replication, marklogic, marklogic-corb

We have created some ingest/harmonize/delete flows/actions, which will be triggered by CORB to do this in a specific 'controlled' order.

We have set up an environment for our Acceptance and Production, with a loadbalancer and also replication (3 machines with identical settings and configuration for MarkLogic are available) + Disaster Recovery (3 servers).

Testing this solution is taking considerable less time on our development environment compared to the Acceptance...

The configuration of our Acceptance servers is signifantly better..

What is causing this performance penalty ?

- indexing is taking place on all 3 replicated machines ?
- replicating data ?
- ......

Comment: Our development machine has no Replication and DR and loadbalancer set-up.

Comment: There could be a number of factors. Have you looked at History to see what the meters data shows? Have you looked for any warnings or error messages in the ErrorLog? You might try disabling replication, or adjusting the lag limit to see if your replica cluster is not keeping up and causing transactions to be throttled. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/dbrep_intro#id_40516

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we will take this in consideration and test with your suggestions again our CORB action. I will let you know the outcome of this...